# How to format a phone number in regex using [Vue 2]

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vuejs2, regex-group

I'm currently trying to create regex code that accomplishes the following:

- Allows for **only** the first character (0th index) in a string to be a '+' symbol **or** a number (0-9).
- Does not allow for non-numerical values (0-9) to be used anywhere else in the string. This means no letters, symbols, or emojis.

Here are examples of strings that would work and pass through with a perfect solution:

- `+1234`
- `1234`

Here are examples of strings that would **not work** and **not pass through** with a perfect solution:

- `abcd`
- `!@#$`
- `+abcd`
- `+!@#$`
- `+++++`
- `+123+45`
- `+ 12345`

The closest I've managed to get is /[^+][^\0-9]+/g - https://regex101.com/r/F8OAGU/1. You'll notice it catches letters and some symbols, but not multiple '+'`s in a row.

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
this.$emit(`phoneEvent`, phoneNumber.replace(/[^+][^\0-9]+/g, ""))
```

Would appreciate any guidance towards a solution. :)

Comment: `/^\+?[0-9]+$/g`

Comment: @SaniHuttunen Am I entering this incorrectly or something? It doesn't seem to match anything at all when testing online - https://regex101.com/r/2Gwk6T/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/uCvi2R/1 Remember to add multiline modifier for your multiple test cases.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen So this is actually the opposite of what I'm looking for considering I'm using the 'replace' function. My original regex was much closer https://regex101.com/r/F8OAGU/1

Comment: This is a typical [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and hence I will vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^\+?[0-9]+$/g
```

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- `\+` matches the character +
- `?` matches the
  previous token between zero and one times
- Match a single character present in the list `[0-9]`
- `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line
- `/g` Global modifier, return all matches

Comment: On a side note: If you're checking a single number (i.e. not a list of numbers) you can omit the `global modifier` and if you're checking a list of numbers then you'd need both the `global modifier` and `multiline modifier`.

Comment: So this is actually the opposite of what I'm looking for considering I'm using the 'replace' function. My original regex was much closer https://regex101.com/r/F8OAGU/1

Comment: Then I don't understand you question. You want to match everything BUT numbers? You want to replace what exactly? Your question asked to match numbers either beginning with `+` or not. The regex I provided matches your reuquest in the question. If you want something completely different then you need to state that in the question.

Comment: You want to replace everything else but phone numbers?
That is not something you want to do (and regex cannot do). You want to extract the phone numbers instead. Use my provided regex pattern and extract the numbers from the string.

Comment: Or you want to "delete" the phone numbers from a string? Then extract them with the provided regex and string replace in the original string.

Comment: This is a typical [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and hence I will vote to close.

Comment: This is not an XY problem. I'm using this code this.$emit(`phoneEvent`, phoneNumber.replace(/[^+][^\0-9]+/g, "")) and I want it to remove non-compatible characters from the input. This means, all the strings that DON'T WORK -- should be removed by this code with the correct Regex. With your regex, it does the total opposite.

Comment: Yes it is since you your questions asks to find phone numbers but you want the opposit...